Laravel Multiple sheets with multiple heading rows
I already achieved the code for two rows but data is not aligning with the rows. I tried several methods to map the data but still the data is showing after the headings


This is what I want to achieved so far, this is the headings and the map
public function headings():array{
    return [
        [
            'Entity Name',
            'Fund Cluster'
        ],
        [
            'Date',
            'Reference',
            'Item Desc',              
        ],
    ];
}

public function map($row): array
{
    $firstRowData = [
        'entity_name' => $row['entity_name'],   // Data for "Entity Name"
        'fund_cluster' => $row['fund_cluster'], // Data for "Fund Cluster"
        'date' => '',                            // Placeholder for the third column (empty in the first row)
    ];
    // Second row of headings
    $secondRowData = [
        'entity_name' => '',         
        'fund_cluster' => '',        
        'date' => $row['date'],    
        'reference' => $row['reference'],   
        'item_desc' => $row['item_desc'],  
    ];
    $mappedData = array_merge($firstRowData, $secondRowData);

    return $mappedData;
}


So why not call array_merge() on the headings like you did with the map code? How to combine two PHP arrays while ignoring keys  I don't know what you expect as output from your map() method call.  We don't have a [mcve] here.  Do you want this behavior in map()? PHP array_merge empty values always less prioritar
